# How to change date formats from this to DD.MM.YYYY?

Tags: apex

I am currently sending emails via Mandrill and SF sends dates like this:

2015-09-08 - How do I format the date to be in DD.MM.YYYY format.

At the moment I simply do: `webinarLocale.StartDate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example should work if you can use a string as the final output, otherwise dates are always displayed in the local context of the user...

```
Date d = date.today();
String dt = DateTime.newInstance(d.year(),d.month(),d.day()).format('d-MM-YYYY');
system.debug(logginglevel.error,dt);
```

Comment: Is it two `d`s ?

Comment: @AliGajani - If you want a two digit day yes

Comment: How do I use dots instead of dashes though?

Comment: @AliGajani - Do you really need me to answer that?

Comment: No. I just replace dashes with dots :)

Comment: @AliGajani - Yup....

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
Date dt = obj.Date__c;

system.debug(dt.day() + '.' + dt.month() + '.' + dt.year());
```

Comment: This would not handle leading zeros.

Comment: That is right. I want leading 0s